# Increment cloned tr label for attribute value

Tags: jquery, html

### What I am Trying

I am trying to add a row with all the form elements when a button is clicked. When the new row is added all ids of form elements will be incremented. Say suppose if by default the id is "username1", then the cloned tr will contain input element with "username2". I need to increment the label for value along with the id.

### JS

```
var count = parseInt($('#counter').val(), 10) + 1;
    $('#counter').val(count);
var x = $('.clone-table tr.default').clone();
    fixIds(x, count);

function fixIds(elem, cntr) {
    $(elem).find("[id]").add(elem).each(function() {
    this.id = this.id.replace(/\d+$/, "") + cntr;
    });
```

### HTML

```
<input type="hidden" id="counter" value="1"/>
.
.
.
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="text" id="username1" name="username[]"/>
    <label for="username1">Username</label>
  <td>
<tr>
```

When the  is cloned I want the label for attribute value "username1" to be incremented along with the input id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Code

```
function fixIds(elem, cntr) {
        $(elem).find("[id]").add(elem).each(function() {
    this.id = this.id.replace(/\d+$/, "") + cntr;
});
$(elem).find('input[name="username[]"]').each(function() {
    $(this)
            .attr('id', $(this).attr('id'))
            .next('label').attr('for', $(this).attr('id'))
});


 });
```

Comment: label values are incrementing, but its not going like 1,2,3. Its going like 1, 12, 123

Comment: i use cntr variable, check cntr variable value pass correctly

Comment: replace var count = parseInt($('#counter').val(), 10) + 1;  with var count = Math.abs($('#counter').val()) + 1;

Comment: still the same result

Comment: fixed it. did some small tweaks in code. Actually in your code you are appending cntr value to the id. When the id is username1 then if cntr value is 2 then the id will become username2

Answer (score 0):

Store the userId in a variable and then increment it when you clone the row. You can alter the IDs before you append the cloned row to the table.

```
var lastUserId = 1;

$('#addRow').click(function() {
    //Clone row
    var $row = $('table tr:last').clone(true);

    //Get row ID
    var $rowInput = $row.find('td > input[id^=username]');

    //Increment ID and append it.
    var $newRowId = $rowInput.attr('id')
        .slice(0, (lastUserId.toString().length * -1)) + (++lastUserId).toString();

    //Replace IDs
    $rowInput.attr('id', $newRowId);
    $row.find('td > label').attr('for', $newRowId);

    //Add row to table
    $('table tbody').append($row);
});
```

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/qww6s9ch/1/